# dynamically change visibility of input text in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a variable that i will pass from my controller to my view, lets call this variable `$validate`. This variable will help us to know in what state is the user in (Update or Save).
I will ask user to input an ID and Password in **Save** state (**input text id = enable, password = visible**)
But in **Update** state, i dont want user to update their ID and they cant see their Password (**input text id = disable, password = invisible**).
Now for the input text id, i could do something like this :
`<input type="text" name="ID_user" class="text"
                    <?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>`
So **no javascript are needed in the input text ID**
My Question are :

1. How to make the input text password invisible according to `$validate` value?
2. Can i use the same way like input text ID?(so no javascript are needed)
   Thanks :D

**Note : i use the same form for Update and Save :D**

Comment: ...why are you sending the 'password' to the view, then back to your controller if you already have it?

Comment: ... and I'm guessing the fact you are able to send the password to the view means you are only storing it as plain text...?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Thanks :D Yes, i know i dont have to send the password to the view however my user will get confuse because the input text password is still there, thats why i want to set it to invisible if the user choose to update their data (i have another form for change password).
I use the same form for save and update :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this - just use a simple 'if' switch statement

```
<html>
   <p>stuff</p>
   <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
   <?php if ($validate!='add') {?>
           <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
           <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
   <?php } else { ?>
           <input type="text" name="id" id="id" disabled="disabled">
   <?php } ?>

</html>
```

edit: I'm assuming you are NOT wanting to 'POST' the password back to yourself when it is an update.

Comment: Thank you :D
But can i use the similiar code like <?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>
I really prefer this way, i tried like this : <?php if($validate!='add'){?><input visible="false"/><?php}?> but it gives me an error @_@

Comment: But WHY are you even putting a 'password' field into the form, if you are hiding it as invisible? That makes no sense - and is a MAJOR security issue...

Comment: Because i tried to use 1 form for multiple function...i dont think it has something to do with the security, because i dont pass the password in the update state. All i want is just make its input field invisible with the help of $validate. Thanks :D

Comment: ok - so if you dont pass the password back - WHY do you need the password field as "invisible"? My answer above means you dont even need to have a "password" field depending upon $validate?

Comment: Yes! you are right, thank you very much! and sorry im a beginner :D